Eclipseを使ったJavaアプリ開発時にコンテキスト・ルートの変更が無視される
症状
Eclipseを使ったJavaアプリ開発時に、「Webプロジェクトの設定」画面からコンテキスト・ルートを設定し、適用ボタンを押すと、設定していた文字列が消えてコンテキストルートが空欄に戻ってしまう。
環境
OS：Windows 11
統合開発環境：pleiades-2022-06-java-win-64bit_20220619
開発言語：openjdk 17.0.4.1 2022-08-12
サーバー：apache-tomcat-9.0.65
再現手順

以下のプロジェクトをクローンURIでEclipseにインポートする。
https://github.com/akb153/jpt_FY25Fall_Intern.git
Eclipseのプロジェクト・エクスプローラーにて「school_library」プロジェクトを右クリックし、「プロパティー」>「プロジェクト・ファセット」>「ファセット・フォームへ変換」をクリック
「プロジェクト・ファセット」のツリー上で「Java」「JavaScript」「動的Webモジュール」にチェックをつけ、「適用して閉じる」をクリック
Eclipseのプロジェクト・エクスプローラーにて「school_library」プロジェクトを右クリックし、「プロパティー」>「Webプロジェクトの設定」をクリック⇒コンテキスト・ルートは空になっており、「コンテキスト・ルートは空にできません」というエラーメッセージが表示される
コンテキスト・ルートに任意の文字列を入力し、「適用」ボタンをクリック。「コンテキスト・ルートの名前変更」ウィンドウが表示されるため「OK」をクリック
コンテキスト・ルートの入力画面に戻るが、コンテキスト・ルート欄は空白のままになっている（5.での変更内容が無視される）



10年ほど前に同じ事象になっているQAを見つけました。
今回はMavenは使っていないのでそのまま参考にすることはできませんが、プロジェクトのインポート時に何かが起きていそうなので、クローンURIを使わない形でのインポートなどを試してみます。
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407906

org.eclipse.wst.common.componentの編集とかもしてみましたが効果なしでした。
挙動的にバグっぽさを感じるのでEclipse Foundationに問い合わせてみます。

すでに似た報告が多数上がっていたので問い合わせはやめました。
代わりに、以下の方法を使ったところ問題を回避してプロジェクトをサーバーで公開できました。
①以下のプロジェクトをクローンURIでEclipseにインポートする。 　　　github.com/akb153/jpt_FY25Fall_Intern.git
②Eclipseのプロジェクト・エクスプローラーの空白部分を右クリック>「新規」「プロジェクト」>「Java」>「Javaプロジェクト」>「次へ」
③プロジェクト名「school_lib」>「次へ」>「完了」
④Eclipseのプロジェクト・エクスプローラーにて「school_lib」プロジェクトを右クリックし、「プロパティー」>「プロジェクト・ファセット」>「ファセット・フォームへ変換」をクリック
⑤「プロジェクト・ファセット」のツリー上で「Java」「JavaScript」「動的Webモジュール」にチェックをつけ、「適用して閉じる」をクリック
⑥「school_library」プロジェクトに入っているソースを全選択し、ドラッグアンドドロップで「school_lib」プロジェクト以下に移動（重複するファイルはすべて上書き）
⑦ファイル移動後の「school_library」プロジェクトは削除し、「school_lib」のプロジェクト名とコンテキスト・ルートを「school_library」に変更
⑧Eclipseのプロジェクト・エクスプローラーにて「school_library」プロジェクトを右クリックし、「プロパティー」>「Javaのビルド・パス」>「ソース」の「school_library/src」を除去し、「フォルダーの追加」にて「school_library/src/main/java」を追加
⑨Tomcatを再起動し、ブラウザから「localhost:8080/school_library/Login」にアクセスするとログイン画面が表示される
